# Softly Transition HTML Images with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to use JS to switch images, the code does what it is supposed to and switches the images, however, I want a fade out-fade in effect to the image transition. I tried to declare a CSS Transition for opacity and change the opacity first, which didn't work, then I tried to change the opacity with plain JS, however that didn't work either, what would be the best way to achieve this?
My Poorly Designed Image Change Code:

```
image = [
    "image_1.png",
    "image_2.png",
    "image_3.jpeg"
];

updateImg = async() => {
    console.log("Pulling Image Change")
    var img = document.getElementById("img-pan");
    console.log(`Got ${img} with current src ${img.src}`)
    var exi_bool = false;
    for(i = 0; i < image.length - 1; i++) {
        if(img.src.endsWith(image[i])) { exi_bool = true; console.log(`Found current src to == image[${i}]`) ;break; }
    }
    if(!exi_bool) {
        img.src = image[0];
    }else {
        if(i < image.length - 1) { i++ }else { i = 0 }
        img.src = image[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well, before you replace the image add a class that define the `opacity` to 0.3 for example.

`document.getElementById("MyElement").classList.add('MyClass');`

when the image change you remove the class.

`document.getElementById("MyElement").classList.remove('MyClass');`

Note that your image has to be set on css as `opacity: 1` and `transition` x seconds.

Comment: It works, sort of, the opacity will change but it removes the class too quickly, I tried to await `setTimeout()` but that didn't help either

Comment: Nevermind, I am an idiot, I awaited timeout on the wrong thing

Answer (score 0):

Will use css style animation, just change class name, is simple to use and build.

but when css animation start to change css property,no way could change same property but other css animation.

```js
let imgArray = [
      'https://fakeimg.pl/100x100/f00',
      'https://fakeimg.pl/100x100/0f0',
      'https://fakeimg.pl/100x100/00f'
    ];
    let img = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
    
    
    //only two function
    async function fadeOut(element) {
      element.className = 'fade-out';
    }
    async function fadeIn(element) {
      element.className = 'fade-in';
    }
    //
    
    
    
    let i = 0;

    function loop() {
      img.src = imgArray[i % 3];
      i++;
      fadeIn(img).then(res => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          fadeOut(img).then(res => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              loop();
            }, 1000);
          })
        }, 1000);
      })
    }
    loop();
```

```css
img {
      position: relative;
      left: 0;  /* or use transform */
      opacity: 1;
      transition: 1s;
      width: 100px;
      display: block;
      margin: auto;
    }

    .fade-in {
      animation: fade-in 1s;
    }

    @keyframes fade-in {
      0% {
        left: 100px; /* or use transform */
        opacity: 0;
      }

      100% {
        left: 0; /* or use transform */
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }

    .fade-out {
      animation: fade-out 1s both;
    }

    @keyframes fade-out {
      0% {
        left: 0; /* or use transform */
        opacity: 1;
      }

      100% {
        left: -100px; /* or use transform */
        opacity: 0;
      }
    }
```

```html
<img src="https://fakeimg.pl/100x100/#f00">
```